# Can i scan a website in nmap?

Tags: networking, port

The Nmap command i wrote: **nmap -A -Pn -sS -T4 -p 1-65535 <my_website_domain>**
and the result is shown ***WARNING: No targets were specified, so 0 hosts scanned.
Nmap done: 0 IP addresses (0 hosts up) scanned in 0.02 seconds***

and also i tried these commands **nmap -A -Pn -sS -T4 <web_domain>**
,-sS scan , -sT scan!!
***i am not getting what's the problem is***. can anyone help me?
***Note:*** I'm doing this legal not illegal, if u can answer then do else do not!

Comment: `sudo nmap -A -Pn -sS -T4 -p 80-83 scanme.nmap.org` works for me, how did you write your domain?

Comment: As http/s://www.example.org ,is it correct?

Comment: Don't include the protocol, use just the domain, eg `www.example.org`

Comment: thank you so much Dear it is solved ;)